# How did OXO get text into this inside feature?

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, plastic

I am a student trying to learn about how OXO made this cup.

Here are some constraints that I know: I figured out that the text on the outside can be made using screen printing, but then I don't think you can use that same tech to print on the inside since it's so tight. I know this is a high volume part so the process has to be scalable. It's also got to be low cost because the total price is under $8. The text also needs to be able to stay on for 10+ years after contact with various fluids since OXO promises durability. Lastly, the material being printed on is Tritan, a food safe plastic material.

Here is the product: https://www.oxo.com/1-cup-angled-measuring-cup-451.html#

Comment: Are you sure it’s not printed on the underside of that slope? Or overmoulded inside?

Comment: The outer one is probably not screen printed, most likely some sort of flexography

Comment: @JonathanRSwift that's a good observation. that's possible. that would make it easier to access by the printing press. but how would you overmold text on an internal feature?

Comment: @joojaa why do you think it's flexography rather than screen printing? I am not familiar with the former and I have seen the latter be used for cylindrical shapes like cans.

Comment: Because flexography is faster and can be accomodated to wierd shapes if needed.

Comment: @joojaa that's brilliant. thank you!

Comment: You print the text on a film, put that film in the mould, and then encase it in plastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my mother in law has one!

**It’s printed on the underside** The red numbers are printed the same way as those on the sides of the jug, and then a layer of white paint is applied on top of that in order to provide contrast when viewing from the top.

[image]

Comment: The product shots on the website doesn't show the white paint at all. Thank you so much for reaching out to your mom! This photo is really helpful.

Just out of curiosity, how does the paint feel? Any idea how they keep the paint on for so long? (something UV based maybe)

Comment: I think it’s just regular paint - there’s a chip visible on the underside in this photo even - it doesn’t wear off fast as the outside doesn’t see heavy wear - if you were washing this up you wouldn’t scrub the outside that much.